# IDA Pro: "File is apple protected"

Tags: ida, macos

I'm trying to disassemble Dock.app on macOS Sierra, and IDA is giving me this error message:

[image]

What does this mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look in macho.cfg you find:

```
// Key used to decrypt apple-protected binaries.
// Due to copyright reasons we cannot publish the key,
// but we can give you clues...
//   http://www.takwing.idv.hk/tech/virtual/faq/no_more_fakesmc.html

SMC_DEVICE_KEY = "";
```

The link mentioned no longer works, but there are many other places on the internet where the key can be found.

Answer (score 4):

Here you have more details about Apple Binary Protection:
[Creating undetected malware for OS X](http://cerbero-blog.com/?p=1311)

Setting `SMC_DEVICE_KEY` value in `~/.idapro/macho.cfg` works fine.

[Hopper Disassembler](https://www.hopperapp.com/) out of the box can decrypt those binaries too.

At last, you can also run [deprotect](https://github.com/nygard/class-dump/blob/master/deprotect.m) from [class-dump](https://github.com/nygard/class-dump/) to decrypt those binaries `(__TEXT,__text)` section.